# On eventide, what can you do if you send one of the balls out of the play area?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

On Eventide, if you leave the island, you abandon the shrine challenge.

But if you throw one of the balls so far away that you have to leave to get the ball, what can you do? Did you just make yourself have to die and restart the challenge?

Comment: I figure that the initial load that either takes your equipment or returns it would also reset the challenge (like the sphere position).

Comment: I had one despawn after losing it in the water and unrecoverable. I circled the island, went as far as I could from it, and ran across it back where I originally found it. I'm not positive if moving far enough away from the ball itself, the ball spawn point, or both, allowed it to despawn, however. Something that could be tested and better formed into an answer...

Comment: That happened to me, and I spent 30 MINUTES  trying to get it up back to land because I didn't have a save file. WARNING, DO NOT USE URBOSA'S FURY NEAR AN ORB THAT JUST MAKES IT FLUNG OFF THE MAP!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attempt to place Cryonis in such a way that the ball rolls off the ice pillar towards the island. And do so over and over again until it gets to shore. But it's probably less tedious and mind-numbing to just restart the whole challenge.

Comment: Alternatively if there is anything you can magnesis you might be able to guide it back in with that too if it's not too far away.

Comment: Unloading the orb is much easier IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Move as far away from the ball as you can, to the opposite point of the island, and don't look towards it. This should cause the ball to unload, which will make it reappear where you first found it.